# Service Virtualization/Mocking Using Karate

Tags: mocking, karate, service-virtualization

We are trying to setup service virtualization/mocking server for our system which is dependent on several other api's/services. We were looking for options to do service virtualization and i was doing some research on the tools/frameworks available in the market. I came across karate among some other options and i really like the way it simplifies automation and testing effort. I would like to know if karate support service virtualization for java springboot api. If yes then what is the good way to start and where to start with karate and service virtualization?

Comment: Yes it does.

The best way is to read the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty

For an actual Spring-Boot mock example, please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/consumer-driven-contracts

Comment: Thanks for replying back with info. Yes i was looking through the example and documentation you mentioned but still kind of confused about the approach i should take to create mock/virtual service. I would like to see if there is another simple example available to create mock service, run it as standalone mock server and call it in other service/project.

Comment: If you think that example is complex, maybe you should give up on mocking :) just my opinion, all the best.

Comment: I got it . i think i was thinking too much on it but it looks simple after running the example. Bdw that was rude man ;). Thanks